# error : Error initializing task XamlG: Not registered task XamlG

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am developing a Xamarin Forms (PCL) application for IOS and Android Platform.

My Xamarin Studio version is 5.5.4 (Build 15). I am on stable channel.

My Xamarin Forms dll version is 1.3.0.6292.

I have also added a Xamarin Forms Labs reference from NuGet, v1.2.0.

Since yesterday, whenever i am building the solution, i get following error:

```
error : Error initializing task XamlG: Not registered task XamlG.
```

Any possible resolution for this error? I have tried clean and build multiple time. Even deleted the entire source code and redownloaded everything from source control but same error.

Comment: Additional info: 
Xamarin.iOS - Version: 8.4.0.47
Xamarin.Android - Version: 4.20.0.28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is silly.

I just recloned the project in a new fresh folder and build it from scratch and it worked. The more i am using Xamarin Forms, the more buggy and unbaked it seems. There are random issues which get fixed just by rebuilding the project. Or like Matt pointed in his answer below, by just restarting the studio. In my programming experience with different IDEs and platforms, only Xamarin seems to have these problems regularly.

Comment: This is a fair call. I like Xamarin a lot, but the tools leave a lot to be desired.

Answer (score 5):

This error can occur if you have upgraded from an older version of Xamarin.Forms to a newer version. The underlying problem is that the wrong Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll is being loaded compared with the one that the custo MSBuild Xamarin.Forms.targets file is expecting.

There is a [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=23993) in Xamarin Studio where the old build Xamarin.Forms build tasks are still used after the NuGet package has been upgraded. You can workaround this by closing and re-opening the solution.

However you say you have deleted the source code and downloaded everything again so it sounds like you have a different problem. It may be that your project is trying to use two different versions of Xamarin.Forms at the same time. I would look at your project files (.csproj) in a text editor and make sure they are all using one version of Xamarin.Forms. Check that they are all referencing a single version of Xamarin.Forms.targets and it is the same version.

Comment: Thanks @Matt-Ward, for me, it was the XF nugget package updated on the main PCL project but not on the platform-specific platform csproj. But then even when updating in all to the same latest version did not work until I restarted XStudio.